# EF Сервис работает некорректно. Не отображается вновь добавленный элемент при следующем запросе

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Есть сервис:

```
public class MYTYPEService : EntityService<MYTYPE>, IMYTYPEService
{
    public MYTYPEService (IMainContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}

public abstract class EntityService<T> : IEntityService<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected IMainContext Context;
    protected IDbSet<T> Dbset;

    public EntityService(IMainContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        Dbset = Context.Set<T>();
    }


    public virtual T Create(T entity)
    {
        try
        {

            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            Dbset.Add(entity);
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return entity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //logging
        }
    }


    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return Dbset.Where(where).ToList();
    }

}
```

Есть контроллер вида:

```
public class MYController : BaseController
{
    private IMYTYPEService myTypeService;

    public MYController (IMYTYPEService _myTypeService)
    {
       myTypeService= _myTypeService;
    }

    public ActionResult Partial(int parent_id, string data)
    {



       MYTYPE newMyType = new MYTYPE();
       newMyType.parent_id = parent_id;
       newMyType.data = data;
       MYTYPEService.Create(newMyType );


       //MYTYPEService= new MYTYPEService(new MainContext);   
       //если раскомментить, тогда всё работает, т.е. вновь добавленный
       //элемент появится на странице (т.е. во viewmodel), иначе нет, 
       //но это явно не подход                

       var viewmodel = MYTYPEService.GetMany(cl => cl.parent_id == parent_id).AsQueryable().ProjectTo<ViewModel>();

        return PartialView("Partial", viewmodel );
    }
}

public class MYTYPE 
{
   [Key]
   public int id { get; set; } //автоинкремент
   public int parent_id {get; set; }
   public string data {get; set;}
}
```

Вопрос, в чем ошибка сервиса, почему добавленный элемент с помощью Create не видно при последующем запросе GetMany? Физически запись в БД присутствует, и если сделать запрос в другом Action методе, тогда GetMany уже увидит новый элемент...

Comment: У вас и другая ересь написана. AsQueryable, например...

Comment: ProjectTo<> требует

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваша проблема - именно в пересоздании сервиса? Кажется, вы пытаетесь заткнуть костылем более глубокую проблему: ваш сервис неправильно работает.

Comment: По поводу `ProjectTo<>` - а вы задумывались, **зачем** он требует `IQueryable<>`?

Comment: А в чем именно его не правильность? Все функции он выполняет корректно.

Comment: Юрий, он не показывает вновь добавленный элемент. Это и есть некорректная работа.

Comment: ну с IQueryable<> и ProjectTo<> я постараюсь разобраться потом, я так понимаю с данной проблемой это не связано, а в чем проблема у сервиса, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Для начала - в сторону стирания ненужного кода из вопроса и выкладывания кода сервиса. Еще можно вопрос переименовать и метки переставить, потому что Autofac тут точно ни при чем, это не он сервис глючить заставил.

Comment: Надеюсь что этот вариант вопроса более адекватен?

Comment: Да. Теперь еще одна непонятка - а как, собственно, связаны объект `newMyType` и `long id`? Почему вы считаете, что новый объект должен попасть в выборку? Если id - это автоинкрементный первичный ключ, то объект никак не может попасть в этот запрос. А если id - что-то другое, то надо уточнить как он назначается, сейчас в коде этого не видно.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не написал. Поправил описание метода и добавил класс MYTYPE